# Can Devise be used for authentication in a Cramp app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, server-sent-events, cramp

I have created an app using the Cramp.in(http://cramp.in) framework. I need to now setup authentication for the application. In Rails i have used Device for this purpose. Can Device be used in a Cramp application or should i use something else ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Devise is built for Rails thus making it deeply coupled to it. So you just can't use it.

Devise being built on top of a Rack middleware named Warden (https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki) it may sounds as a solution, but Cramp by being asynchronous can't use these directly (see http://cramp.in/documentation#rack-middlewares).

All middleware shipped with Rack are available in an asynchronous flavour (https://github.com/rkh/async-rack) but Warden isn't one of these. You may want to spend some time modifying it so it runs in an async environment (I guess you'd make yourself a lot of friends doing that :)

Conclusion : You may want to roll your own authentication solution.

*Since sinatra is supported through an async module, you might want to look at the Sinatra authentication solutions that are available but I doubt they would run without any modification.*